# Parsing a nested array where key is a float in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following query that I need to get a value from a nested array. I'm using laravel 5.4 in case that matters.

```
$usersstyle = DB::connection('mysql2')
  ->table('wp_rg_lead_detail')
  ->where('lead_id', $collection->id)
  ->get();
dd($usersstyle);
```

This has an output of:

```
Collection {#396 ▼
#items: array:49 [▼
0 => {#406 ▶}
1 => {#407 ▶
18 => {#428 ▼
  +"id": 655
  +"lead_id": 67
  +"form_id": 8
  +"field_number": 51.0
  +"value": "Yes"
}
19 => {#429 ▼
  +"id": 656
  +"lead_id": 67
  +"form_id": 8
  +"field_number": 6.1
  +"value": "Sleeveless"
}
20 => {#430 ▼
  +"id": 657
  +"lead_id": 67
  +"form_id": 8
  +"field_number": 6.2
  +"value": "Jacket"
}
21 => {#431 ▼
  +"id": 658
  +"lead_id": 67
  +"form_id": 8
  +"field_number": 6.3
  +"value": "Cardigan"
}
22 => {#432 ▶}
```

I have tried the following, but it returns the 1st instance of the field_number, and ignores the 6.2 and 6.3. How do I do this and keep all the floats as keys.

```
 $keyed = $usersstyle->keyBy('field_number')->all();
```

I want to get something like the below. With out a foreach loop to display that.

```
 echo $6.3->value;
```

with the result being Cardigan

I have also used

```
  $grabvalues = $usersstyle->whereIn('field_number', 80.3)->toArray();
```

this returns an array or if i drop the toArray a collection that I still need to loop through to get the value

Comment: what you mean by this line >> I want to get something like the below. With out a foreach loop to display that. can you explain ?

Comment: @MinarMnr yes since I want to get the 'value' for the associated field_number meaning If I do something like the following $msshirt = 6.1->value; then when i call $msshirt I want it to give me 'sleeveless'

Comment: after this line $keyed = $usersstyle->keyBy('field_number')->all();
use foreach loop you will get your value .

Comment: @MinarMnr yes with a foreach loop it I currently do something like the code below it gives me a value but I don't want to do that for each time I want to set a variable. since there is a lot of field_numbers.  

foreach ($keyed as $usersform)

    {{$usersform->value}}<br>

    endforeach

Comment: Actually i am not clear about your reasons not to use foreach . Just saying you need not use foreach each time before setting a variable . You just use foreach once , then store those values in an array ... then use array index to set a variable .

Comment: @MinarMnr I'm confused about what you mean. I would use a for each and store them in an array. How do I later call the value that is paired with field_number: 6.3. I'm currently trying to make an array where the $keys are the field numbers and the values are 'value' values. if that is done with a foreach loop I would love to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a bunch of test.. Here is the answer I came up with that worked for me. if someone knows how to write this better please submit.

```
  $usersstyle = DB::connection('mysql2')
  ->table('wp_rg_lead_detail')
  ->where('lead_id', $collection->id)
  ->get()

  ;
  $newkeys = $usersstyle->pluck('field_number');
  $values = $usersstyle->pluck('value');
  $result = $newkeys->combine($values)->toArray();
  dd($result["6.1"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : [This doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) may help you .

```
$plucked = $usersstyle->pluck('field_number', 'value');

$plucked->all();
```

Another way :

```
$fieldValue = $usersstyle->map(function ($users) {
    return collect($users->toArray())
        ->only(['field_number', 'value'])
        ->all();
});
```

Comment: This returns the keys as the values. how would I call or set a variable when I know the field_number but not the value?

Comment: i think second one  will give your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your help @minar